# Powershell search files sorted by special date

Tags: windows, powershell

Whenever i try the following command to get all files filtered by a date

```
Get-ChildItem –Recurse | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt "01.01.2014"}
```

it still shows me all files and not filtered.

Output looks like this

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                    
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                    
d-----       15.03.2019     19:13                .3DF Zephyr Free                                                                                                        
d-----       17.08.2019     14:39                .android                                                                                                                
d-----       12.04.2020     23:36                .cache                                                                                                                  
d-----       24.06.2020     19:24                .config                                                                                                                 
d-----       24.11.2020     19:06                .dbus-keyrings
```

...
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: All the items shown in the output has a `LastWriteTime` date that's newer (so "greater than") Jan 1st 2014, what's the problem?

Comment: ah thank you so -gt stands for greater than. But i only want to filter by that special date. is there any other parameter for that?

Comment: Check out [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1) about comparison operators.

Comment: You mean you only want files that were last written to _on_ that specific date?

Comment: yes exactly, i guess i just read the docs first, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is doing it's job. Everything there is complying to greater than the specified date.

If you wish to filter by that specific date only, change the -gt (greater than) to -eq (equal) and it should do so.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, `-gt` is the "greater than" comparison operator, and all the directories shown in your post has a date that's newer, so it's working exactly as advertised.

---

If you want only files and directories where the `LastWriteTime` value is sometime during that specific date, you can do:

```
# We want values in between the date at midnight, and the next day at midnight
$from = (Get-Date -Day 1 -Month 1 -Year 2014).Date
$to   = $from.AddDays(1)

Get-ChildItem -Recurse { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $from -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $to }
```

That is, we want file system items that are *newer* than Jan 1st 2014 at midnight, but *older* than Jan 2nd 2014

Comment: Shorter: `{ $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq $from }`

Comment: @zett42 Thanks. I deliberately chose not to suggest `.Date` because it's less intuitive, but yes, it's absolutely an option, feel free to post an answer!